# Cannot install netflix desktop on ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, netflix, netflix-desktop

I am trying to install netflix desktop version to be able to watch movies offline and I am getting this error.

```
E: Unable to locate package netflix-desktop
```

I am running these commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:ehoover/compholio

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

and are these repos still supported? or any suggestion that I can watch it offline on chrome as well?

Please help me Durdana

Comment: Those packages NEVER allowed to "watch movies offline", they allowed to watch them online. They are not supported for a long time.

Comment: Please note that it you visit the [pipelight/stable launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/~pipelight/+archive/ubuntu/stable?field.series_filter=) you will find that it does not support release beyond 16.04

Comment: And it seems that Silverlight is dead in general. Someone has told OP that they can download movies from Netflix using Ubuntu. :-))

Answer (score 2):

> and are these repos still supported?

No and they never where supported.

> or any suggestion that I can watch it offline on chrome as well?

The only way is to use the netflix app for Windowss, Android or MacOS so no if you want to use netflix to watch a series or movie. For a notebook I would suggest installing windows, netflix app in there and watch from that.

Comment: OP probably has the app already, but they want to watch offline. Using that repo I could watch Netflix some time ago.

Comment: the app abused a bug in the protocol they used ;-) bug got fixed (they started using pipelight). app got killed.